# router outlet cause the page to go up, how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

When a user clicks on a specific row the router-outlet is called and a page is displayed below that row.  The problem is when the user clicks on the row the page is displayed fine but, the master page goes up (scroll top)..so the user has to scroll down to see the (router-outlet) child page data.

How can I prevent the scroll top?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <div *ngFor="let values of domResponseData;let i = index" (window:scroll)="onScroll($event)">
        <tr style="text-align: center" (click)="showDetails(values,'showdet',i)" [class.selected]="checkIndex==i">
            <td style="text-align: left" width="30%">
                <div>{{values.title}} {{values.firstName}} {{values.middleName}} {{values.lastName}}</div>
                ( {{values.registeredEmail}} )</td>
            <td width="40%">
                <div>Transaction-ID - {{values.transactionID}}</div>{{values.date | date:'full'}}</td>
            <td width="500px">
                <div>{{values.bookingstatus}}</div>Total Price :- ₹ {{values.totalPrice}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="checkIndex==i" style="background-color: #e4e5e6; " id="jump">
            <td colspan="3">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <tr style="text-align: center" (click)="showMore()">Show More</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so where is `router outlet`

Comment: What is your question with all that code?

Comment: when a user click on a specific row the router-outlet is called and a page is displayed below that row. now the problem is when the user clicks on the row the page is displayed fine .but the master page goes up(scroll top)..so the user has to scroll down to see the (router-outlet) child page data

Comment: Can we make a guess it is the `(click)="showDetails(values,'showdet',i)"` at fault here? Can you post that functions code (and anything it calls)?  OR is it the `(click)="showMore()"` code.  Please post a minimal complete question that includes the ability to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Welcome to StackOverflow, we are more than happy to assist you in resolution of well asked questions!

Comment: sorry mark for that you couldn't understand the problem,this first time i  am asking a question...here is the showdetails() function

Comment: showDetails(specificData, type, index) {
    if (type == "searchres") {      this.checkIndexSearch = index;
      this.checkIndex = "nothing";
    } else if (type == "showdet") {
      this.checkIndex = index;
      this.checkIndexSearch = "nothing";}
    if (this.checkIndex == index) {
      this.hideDetails = !this.hideDetails }
    if (this.checkIndexSearch == index) {
      this.hideDetails = !this.hideDetails
    }
 this.router.navigate(['Hotels/HotelsBookings/DomHotelsBookings/DomHotelsBookingsDetails'],{ queryParams: { "details": JSON.stringify(specificData) } });
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well kind of found a hack...

```
setTimeout(function(){var y=window.scrollY+50;
    window.scrollTo(0, y);
},150);
```

Comment: This does as you state appear to be just a hack to obfuscate the real issue, hiding it rather than resolving it.